# differentiability of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{|x|})$

Tags: derivatives

How to justify, the following function is differentiable at origin or not?

$f(x) = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{|x|}$ if $x \ne 0$, $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ if $x = 0$.

Even though mod x is not behaves well at the origin, since we are composing the mod x with the nice function $\tan^{-1}(x)$, I am guessing that above defined $f$ is differentiable at 0. But how to show that rigorously?

I think my guess is correct.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The function can be simplified:
$\arctan(\tfrac1{|x|})=\tfrac{\pi}2-\arctan{|x|}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Bati ... and $x \neq 0$ :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that
$$
f(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)=\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}(|x|)
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{-\tan^{-1}(h)}{h}=-1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{-\tan^{-1}(-h)}{h}=1
$$
Since the two limits don't match, the function is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Here is a plot that shows the slope of $1$ to the left and the slope of $-1$ to the right:

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

Comment: really nice answer . . . thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x}}
={1 \over \pars{1/\verts{x}}^{2} + 1}\,
\pars{-\,{1 \over \verts{x}^{2}}}\sgn\pars{x}
=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{\sgn\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}}\,,\qquad x \not=0
$$

> Note that
>   $$
> \lim_{x\ \to\ 0^{-}}\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x} = 1
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> \lim_{x\ \to\ 0^{+}}\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x} = -1
> $$

Namely,
$$\left.\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x}\right\vert_{\,x\ =\ 0^{-}}
\not=\left.\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x}\right\vert_{\,x\ =\ 0^{+}}
$$

> such that $\ds{\left.\totald{\arctan\pars{1/\verts{x}}}{x}\right\vert_{\,x\ =\ 0}}$
>   $\ds{\underline{\tt\mbox{doesn't exist}}}$.

Comment: Since this tells what the derivative is away from the point in question, it would be nice to mention that if the limit of the derivative from the left of $x_0$ and the limit of the derivative from the right of $x_0$ exist and are not equal, then the derivative does not exist at $x_0$ (say using the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) or something similar).

Comment: @robjohn It's pretty clear from the result.

Comment: @robjohn I add the "Note that...". Thanks.

Comment: I meant that because $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(\xi)\text{ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $0$}$$ we get that the left derivative at $0$ is $1$ and the right derivative at $0$ is $-1$. Perhaps that is what you meant by $$\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\arctan(1/|x|)} {\mathrm{d}x}\,\right|_{x=0^-} \quad\text{and}\quad \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}\arctan(1/|x|)} {\mathrm{d}x}\,\right|_{x=0^+}$$ However, those seem to indicate values just to the left and right of $0$, which is different.